# ngModel make datePicker date of today return null

Tags: angular, datepicker

My date picker is set default to today, which benefit the status of what my code is running at the moment. I want to be able to pass the value of it so I use ngModel and it make my datePicker null. I found that ngInit can hard code default value but the problem is I don't know what represent dateTime.Now in ngInit.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Angular forms</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [formControl]="date" [(ngModel)]="datePicker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1 [(ngModel)]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove ngmodel from `<mat-datepicker` like this `<mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>`

Here is an example project which has developed using mat-date-picker with ngModel
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cj6bjs?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html

Other than that u can find this example in Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlerqrdamjl?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.html and it has developed using Reactive forms.